# Can 'where' describe what is not a place?

Tags: grammar, relative-adverbs

> It's a style of dancing where we don't use our hands.

Why the word 'where' is used even though 'a style of dancing' isn't a place?

Comment: Less common in this *exact* context, but still relatively natural in English, we can use ***chronologically metaphorical*** "when" instead of (spatially metaphorical) "where". [*Labored is used of a style of writing **when** it shows signs of the care and work bestowed upon it*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Labored+is+used+of+a+style+of+writing+when+it+shows+signs+of+the+care+and+work+bestowed+upon+it%22)

Comment: @FumbleFingers thank you. Then do you think 'when' fits the best in that sentence out of 'when/where/in which'?

Comment: No - as I said, "when" is less common in your *exact* example than "where". Note that "in which" is just another type of "spatial metaphor" (sub-type ***container metaphor***). The general idea being that [***“All language is metaphor”.***](https://medium.com/@monkindocs/all-language-is-metaphor-is-one-of-my-favourite-richard-rohr-quotes-5e92cfcc9fdb)

Comment: Syntactically, the preposition "where" is mainly used with locative antecedents, but it also turns up quite often with nouns less likely to suggest a loctaion. In both cases, "where" functions as an adjunct in clause structure with a meaning here of, roughly, "in such a style of dancing". "When" would be inappropriate here.